# Continuing pages need a heading

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to modify a .cls file to write down my thesis, in particular I am trying to add modify the CITED LITERATURE, and allow Continuing pages to have heading, CITED LITERATURE (Continued). Any ideas on how to modify the following code to make it CITED LITERATURE (continued) for continuing pages?

```
\def\bibliography#1{
\clearpage
\typeout{CITED LITERATURE.}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
{\protect\xnumberline{\ }CITED LITERATURE}
\def\section@mark{CITED LITERATURE}
\pagestyle{pageontop}
\thispagestyle{pageontop}
\@makeschapterhead{\section@mark}\par
\begin{singlespace}
\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}\fi
\@input{\jobname.bbl}
\end{singlespace}}
```

Any ideas on which command I have to modify?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please provide a minimal working example. And please do not change classes. If you really have to do, make the change obvious by adding a date and your name in the file.

Comment: what do you mean do not chagnes class, then how am I supposed to makes changes?

Comment: By Patching the class, if it doesn't suit your needs. If you look around the internet for *one* special file, and find a few thousand with minimal changes, just because people do not get the hang of a little copyright and licence note, you will be just as frustrated as i am. So, don't change class and/or package files, and if you do, leave a comment and even better, also rename the class to make it even more obvious that it got changed.

Comment: @Henry: We need to know how you write your existing headings? Using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)? Where is the page style `pageontop` defined and what does it look like?

Comment: If your class is reasonably well designed, this can be done at the document (i.e., `.tex`) level. Can you provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) starting `\documentclass{<whatever class>}` and ending with `\end{document}` to see where the problems are? If you are using a difficult-to-find `.cls`, please provide a link to it as well.

Comment: are there any news here?